# Pass null via a variable in mysqli::query

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a special case which requires using mysqli::query rather than mysqli::prepare.  I am trying to pass null via a variable to a stored procedure.  The following which works with a prepared statement:

```
$val = null;
$stmt = $this->db->prepare('CALL my_stored_procedure(?, ?)');
$stmt->bind_param('ii', $this->id, $val);
etc...
```

does not work with a query:

```
$val = null;
$qry = $this->db->query("CALL my_stored_procedure($this->id, $val)");
etc...
```

results in:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1, )'
```

I can explicitly pass null ok, but this does me no good.

Again, I can't use a prepared statement in this case.  Is there a way to pass null to a mysqli query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you use this statements:

```
$procedureArguments = '$this->id, ' . ( is_null($val) ? 'NULL' : $val );
$qry = $this->db->query('CALL my_stored_procedure(' . $procedureArguments . ')');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So does this work, because it is passing the MySQL keyword 'NULL'?

Comment: The $val variable is interpolated to the empty string `''` when encapsulated within a string defined with double quotes. When passing the string NULL, there is indeed no interpolation. Defining your query using single quotes would not work either as the string '$val' would be passed as argument of your procedure instead of the actual variable value.